# ¿Qué significa este mensaje que me ha proporcionado Valgrind?

Tags: c++, sfml

Estoy elaborando un videojuego con c++ y SFML en Ubuntu. Al ejecutar mi programa, me detiene la ejecución de mi programa con el error **"Segmentation fault"**.

Buscando soluciones en Internet, he encontrado una herramienta que proporciona información sobre errores relacionados con el mal uso de la memoria, etc.

Al ejecutarlo,me ha proporcionado la siguiente información, pero **no se como interpretarla correctamente para encontrar el error:**

```
==22886== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22886== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22886== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22886== Command: ./galaga
==22886== 
Child local position: (100.000000;500.000000)
==22886== Invalid read of size 8
==22886==    at 0x4014E8: Entity::GetPosition(Entity::SPACE) (Entity.cpp:44)
==22886==    by 0x4016A8: Entity::SetParent(Entity*) (Entity.cpp:92)
==22886==    by 0x401B43: Game::Game() (Game.cpp:25)
==22886==    by 0x40252C: main (main.cpp:5)
==22886==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22886== 
==22886== 
==22886== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==22886==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==22886==    at 0x4014E8: Entity::GetPosition(Entity::SPACE) (Entity.cpp:44)
==22886==    by 0x4016A8: Entity::SetParent(Entity*) (Entity.cpp:92)
==22886==    by 0x401B43: Game::Game() (Game.cpp:25)
==22886==    by 0x40252C: main (main.cpp:5)
==22886==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22886==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22886==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22886==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22886==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==22886== 
==22886== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22886==     in use at exit: 6,761,843 bytes in 2,269 blocks
==22886==   total heap usage: 11,939 allocs, 9,670 frees, 232,826,337 bytes allocated
==22886== 
==22886== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22886==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22886==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22886==      possibly lost: 360,477 bytes in 67 blocks
==22886==    still reachable: 6,401,366 bytes in 2,202 blocks
==22886==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==22886==                         newarray           : 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==22886==                         multipleinheritance: 104 bytes in 1 blocks
==22886==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22886== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22886== 
==22886== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22886== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
```

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un segmentation fault, es que te estás metiendo a partes de la memoria en el sistema que no deberías. checa que no tengas algo, como un arreglo o un apuntador que esté entrando a lugares erroneos.

Comment: Para saber donde tienes problemas, deberíamos echarle un ojo al código, no somos magos de las referencias :(, aunque si solo quieres saber lo que significa, ya tienes la respuesta.